# JSDoc ts annotations for generic-ish base class (VS Code)

Tags: javascript, class, jsdoc, radix

I'm trying to use JSDoc annotations for a base class where a constructor param (and some getter/method return vals) will be the classes which extend the base class.

Is there a way to specify that `@template` must be derived from base class?

For context I'm writing an abstraction for file system (files + folders) where their name on disk may contain `#tags` - the bulk of code is the same, hence desire for base class, but there are some subtle differences depending on whether it's file or folder (eg. for files the `.ext` is after the `#tags` thus a file name needs slightly different parsing to a folder name). Additionally, there will be classes derived from the file/folder classes, eg. certain parts of the folder tree merit contextual helper methods.

```js
/**
 * @template TParent the parent item, or `null` if root item
 * @type Base<TParent?, string, boolean>
 */
class Base {

  /** @type {TParent?} parent item or `null` if root
  #parent

  /** @type {Set<string>} list of tags from parsed item name
  #tags

  /** @type {boolean} `true` if this item represents a file
  #isFile

  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {TParent?} parent - the parent item, or `null` if root
   * etc...
   */
  constructor(parent, name, isFile = false) {
    this.#parent = parent
    this.#isFile = isFile
    this.#tags = this.#parse(name)
  }

  /** @returns {TParent} parent item, or `null` if root
  get parent() { return this.#parent }

  get tags() { return this.#tags }

  #parse(name) { return new Set() }

  methodActsOnParent() {
    const goo = this.parent?.tags.has("#Goo") ?? false
    // ...                   ^ TParent might not have .tags
  }
}

class Folder extends Base {
  // folder specific stuff
  constructor(...) { ... }
}

class File extends Base {
  // file specific stuff
  constructor(...) { ... }
}

// in some external file:

class Foo extends Folder {
  // foo specific stuff
  constructor(...) { ... }

  /** @returns {TParent} */
  get parent() { return this.parent }
}
```

Is there some way to say " `TParent` must be derived from `Base` " so the code hints, etc., know that the base properties/methods/etc will be available?

And, if I know `class Foo` will *always* have a parent (it's never root), is there some way to specify that, given that `Base` class allows `null` for `parent`? That way I could reduce null checking without resorting to `// @ts-ignore` cheats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a constraint on generic type by `@template {boolean} T`. This is the equivalent of TypeScript `Foo<T extends boolean>`

```js
/**
 * @template {Base<any> | null} T
 */
class Base {
  /**@type {T}*/
  #parent;

  constructor(/**@type {T}*/parent) {
    this.#parent = parent;
  }

  get parent() { return this.#parent; }

  methodActsOnParent() {
    this.parent.methodActsOnParent();
  }
}

/**
 * @template {Base<any> | null} T
 * @extends {Base<T>}
 */
class Foo extends Base {
}

const b = new Base(new Base(null));
b.parent.parent;
b.parent.parent.methodActsOnParent();

const f = new Foo(new Foo(null));
f.parent.parent;
f.parent.parent.methodActsOnParent();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had no idea a template could be constrained - that's perfect for what I was trying to achieve - thanks!